# Button inside datagrid Command Property

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` with following XAML. First of all the `Button` inside the grid doesn't get a blue styling and secondly when the button is pressed, the `Command` property is not working but the `OnClick` is working. In the view model I have `RelayCommand` implementation which works well with other controls only the button in the `DataGrid` seems to have an issue.

```
 <DataGrid 
   x:Name="dgEntities" 
   Width="650" 
   Height="239" 
   Margin="40,-48,65,-8" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding JobEntities}" 
   AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status">
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <Button 
                  Margin="5" 
                  Content="{Binding TaskDetails[0].Status,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
                  Command="{Binding HypelinkCommand}" 
                  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dgEntities,Path=SelectedItem}"
                  Cursor="Hand" 
                  Click="Button_Click">
                  <Button.Template>
                     <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline">
                           <ContentPresenter />
                        </TextBlock>
                     </ControlTemplate>
                  </Button.Template>
                  <Button.Style>
                     <Style TargetType="Button">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                     </Style>
                  </Button.Style>
               </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <CheckBox Name="chkHeaderExtract" Checked="ChkHeaderExtract_OnChecked" Unchecked="ChkHeaderExtract_OnUnchecked"/>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <CheckBox Name="chkExtract" IsChecked="{Binding TaskDetails[0].IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status">
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <Button 
                  Margin="5" 
                  Content="{Binding TaskDetails[1].Status,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
                  Command="{Binding HypelinkCommand}" 
                  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dgEntities,Path=SelectedItem}"
                  Cursor="Hand">
                  <Button.Template>
                     <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline">
                           <ContentPresenter />
                        </TextBlock>
                     </ControlTemplate>
                  </Button.Template>
                  <Button.Style>
                     <Style TargetType="Button">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                     </Style>
                  </Button.Style>
               </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <CheckBox Name="chkHeaderTransform" Checked="ChkHeaderTransform_OnChecked" Unchecked="ChkHeaderTransform_OnUnchecked"/>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <CheckBox Name="chkTransform" IsChecked="{Binding TaskDetails[1].IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status">
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <Button 
                  Margin="5" 
                  Content="{Binding TaskDetails[2].Status,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
                  Command="{Binding HypelinkCommand}" 
                  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dgEntities,Path=SelectedItem}"
                  Cursor="Hand" 
                  Foreground="Blue">
                  <Button.Template>
                     <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline">
                           <ContentPresenter />
                        </TextBlock>
                     </ControlTemplate>
                  </Button.Template>
               </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <CheckBox Name="chkHeaderLoad" Checked="ChkHeaderLoad_OnChecked" Unchecked="ChkHeaderLoad_OnUnchecked"/>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <CheckBox Name="chkLoad" IsChecked="{Binding TaskDetails[2].IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding EntityName}"  Header="Entity" Width="150"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

CODE as posted as comment instead of update to original post.

```
private RelayCommand<object> _hyperlinkInstance; 
public ICommand HypelinkCommand 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        if(_hyperlinkInstance==null) 
               _hyperlinkInstance = new RelayCommand<object>(openDialog); 
        return _hyperlinkInstance; 
    } 
} 

private void openDialog(object obj) 
{ 
    JobConfigurationResults results = obj as JobConfigurationResults; 
    jeresult = JobEntities.SingleOrDefault(
                           x => x.JobEntityId == results.JobEntityId); 
}
```

Comment: Is `HypelinkCommand` against same view model as `TaskDetails` (the view model behind each `DaraGrid` row)? Also what do you mean by _doesn't get a blue styling_? Does it mean that `Button` text does not turn blue?

Comment: yes the HyperLinkCommand is against the same view model as TaskDetails. The blue styling means since i have the setter property value set to blue I expect that the button would look as a hyperlink but it show as a black colored font.

Comment: `HypelinkCommand` or `HyperLinkCommand`? Can you show definition or that property?

Comment: Have you tried '<Setter Property="Button.Foreground" value="Blue"'

Comment: Hey dkozl yes its HypelinkCommand.. I just copied and pasted the ICommand implementation from View model.

Comment: Hey Bill I have tried Button.Foreground but still it dosent work.

Comment: Hey dkzol here is the code.

private RelayCommand<object> _hyperlinkInstance;
public ICommand HypelinkCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if(_hyperlinkInstance==null)
                _hyperlinkInstance=new RelayCommand<object>(openDialog);
                return _hyperlinkInstance;
            }
        }

        private void openDialog(object obj)
        {
            JobConfigurationResults results = obj as JobConfigurationResults;
            jeresult = JobEntities.SingleOrDefault(x => x.JobEntityId == results.JobEntityId);

        }

Comment: @nikhil, I edited your original post with the code.  You can always edit as I did to provide more info to others.

Comment: Thanks DRapp I fixed the issue by specifying the relative source to the Window.